# Javascript: Cypress: select sample with not contain value

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-xpath

I want to select a random value from a dropdown, with the restriction that a specific value should not be selected.

```
    const initialOrderReason = cy.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]");
    tkm
      .dropdownOptions()
      .should("be.visible")
      .then((options) => {
        cy.get(Cypress._.sample(options))
          .not.contain(initialOrderReason)
      });
```

how is it possible?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are wanted to do from your code. Are you only wanting to validate the dropdown doesn't contain the initial order reason?

Comment: let me explain it this way. in a dropdown there are 5 choices. A, B, C, D and E. Now you want a random value to be selected that is not "C", as an example.

Comment: You might consider using the `window` command to get a callback function containing the DOM.  Then use standard javascript code to extract your options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot relevant code that you have not shown, including the HTML but here's my solution based on what you've given

`cy.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")` should be accessed it via `.then()` instead of the  returned value.

And for all elements extract the text of the elements.

```js
cy.xpath('//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')
  .invoke('text')                   // extract text
  .then(initial => {

  tkm.dropdownOptions().should("be.visible")
    .then((options) => {
      const texts = [...options].map(option => option.innerText)    // extract texts

      const notInitial = texts.filter(text => text !== initial)     // filter out initial

      const random = Cypress._.sample(notInitial)   // random other value
      
      // Assuming "//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]" gives a <select> element
      cy.xpath('//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]').select(random)

    });

  cy.xpath('//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')       // requery the dropdown
    .should("not.have.text", initial);  // to allow DOM to change 
})
```

Comment: works pretty well. ty Mate